# Error using retrofit in android app

Tags: android, get, retrofit

I am using retrofit 1.8 for my android application to send get request to the following link https://hamadataha-alfylovealfy.c9users.io/api/posts/1 . This is the class where I put the interface

```
package base;


import model.User;
import retrofit.Callback;
import retrofit.http.GET;
import retrofit.http.Path;

public class Interfaces {
    public interface getUser {
        @GET("/api/posts/2")
        public void getUser(Callback<User> response);
    }
}
```

and this is the RetrofitSingleton class
package base;

```
import retrofit.*;

public class RetrofitSingleton {
    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://hamadataha-alfylovealfy.c9users.io";

    private static RestAdapter restAdapter = null;


    public static RestAdapter getInstance(){
        if (restAdapter == null){
            restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                    .setEndpoint(BASE_URL)
                    .build();
        }
        return restAdapter;
    }

}
```

In my activity, i call the request like this

```
public void ApiTest(){
        Interfaces.getUser call = RetrofitSingleton.getInstance().create(Interfaces.getUser.class);
        call.getUser( new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void success(User user, Response response) {
                setCurrentUser(new User("yessss", "yessss", "yessss"));
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                setCurrentUser(new User("no,", "no", "no"));
                Log.d("hello", error.toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

However it always ends with failure with the following in the logcat

```
retrofit.RetrofitError: No static field METHODS of type Ljava/util/Set; in class Lcom/squareup/okhttp/internal/http/HttpMethod; or its superclasses (declaration of 'com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpMethod' appears in /data/app/com.karim.m3-2/base.apk)
```

Any idea what this error maybe?

Comment: please post your entire stacktrace and maybe the user model you are using for this call. Also please post your Gradle File. From what I can make out it looks like you are doing everything correctly. This seems like a library mismatch. Like something is deprecated